# How do I use requestString in this circumstance

Tags: python, jes

i have an assignment for a class and we have be able to write a function that will select, using `pickAFile()`, a picture file to be opened.

If cancel is pressed in the `pickAFile()` dialogue box, then you must ask the user if it was a mistake.

If it was a mistake, open the `pickAFile()` dialogue again, and repeat until it is either not a mistake, or a picture file was selected.

If a picture file is selected, return the `made` picture, otherwise (i.e. cancel was pushed and the user indicated that it was NOT a mistake) return an error message.

This is what I have so far:

```
def assign3A():

  f = pickAFile()
  cancel = requestString("Did you intentionally press Cancel? Type 'yes' for mistake or hit Cancel for")

  if ans == 'yes':
      print "cancel was deliberatley preesed"
      return
  else:
      f = pickAFile()
  if f !='None':
      print "..."
      return makePicture(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've used JES (my first Uni class!) but I can see one error in your code.

Look at these two lines:

```
cancel = requestString("Did you intentionally press Cancel? Type 'yes' ...")

if ans == 'yes':
```

Do you see it?

Comment: im sorry im really new to jes and this is my first uni class for it, i dont see a problem

Comment: One of the best ways to work out where your program is going wrong is to go through it, line by line, and write out what's happening.


Your program is saying:


1. Run the method pickAFile and store it in variable "f".
2. Ask the user for some input and store it in variable "cancel".
3. Read the variable "ans" to see if what it says.


See it now?